# Check change in file extension before file upload

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, mime-types

I want to detect if user has maliciously changed the extension of a file, before uploading it on our site.

We are on ASP.NET Core 3.1

System should only allow certain file types to be uploaded. For example is user renames .exe to .pdf before upload, site should be able to detect and throw error.

IFormFile ContentType does not work as it doesn't detect the original file extension.

Is there any other way? Somehow detect the original Mimetype of the file?

Thanks

Comment: You can't rely on file name extensions; you have to inspect file signatures or magic bytes.

Comment: I don't think it's feasible. I've been bypassing that on Facebook for years with .7z or .zip extension. You can look at some metadata in the file to check what it really is, but covering all the possible extensions is just undoable.

Comment: You're asking the web server to guess what a user on a remote computer may have done 2 days before uploading a file. That's impossible. You simply *can't* depend on the extension to block file types. It's actually far safer to use `ContentType` to check what the browser thinks the actual file type is. In the end though, you'll have to check the files' header/magic number

Answer (score -1):

You could check the file type based on the magic number. Code as below:

```
    public IActionResult FileUpload()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult FileUpload(FileViewModel fileviewmodel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                fileviewmodel.File.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream);
                reader.BaseStream.Position = 0x0; // The offset you are reading the data from    
                byte[] data = reader.ReadBytes(0x10); // Read 16 bytes into an array    
                string data_as_hex = BitConverter.ToString(data);
                //reader.Close();

                // substring to select first 11 characters from hexadecimal array    
                string file_signature = data_as_hex.Substring(0, 11); //pdf: 25-50-44-46  Excel: 50-4B-03-04

                // according to the file_signature value to decide whether need to insert the data into database or return error.
                // Upload the file if less than 2 MB
                if (memoryStream.Length < 2097152)
                {
                    var newfile = new AppFile()
                    {
                        Name = fileviewmodel.Name,  
                        Content = memoryStream.ToArray()
                    };
                     
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("File", "The file is too large.");
                }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

View Page:

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.FileViewModel 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="FileUpload">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <dl>
                    <dt>
                        <label asp-for="File"></label>
                    </dt>
                    <dd>
                        <input asp-for="File" type="file">
                    </dd>
                </dl>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Test result:

For the .pdf file, the `file_signature` will be `25-50-44-46`, and for the .exe file, the `file_signature` value is `4D-5A-90-00`. If you change the .exe file extension to `.pdf`, the `file_signature` is `4D-5A-90-00`.

Then, you could according to the file_signature value to decide whether need to insert the data into database or return error.

Reference [Find File Type From Magic Number Of File In MVC 5](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a8024d/how-to-find-file-type-from-magic-number-of-file-in-mvc/)

Comment: Copying the file to memory can be as bad if not *worse* - a malicious user could post big files to the server and cause it to crash. `BinaryReader` isn't needed to just read 11 bytes either. There's certainly no need to convert those bytes to strings and back

Comment: You should be really, REALLY careful when copying anything from that site. And google specific phrases first, to find where articles were "borrowed" from. Quite often the original article is a lot better than the "borrowed" one. Or the "borrowing" may have happened years ago from eg MSDN or `learn.microsoft.com`, with the original article edited to fix bugs, mistakes, or add new information